# Can't type in text field on popup lightbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, textinput

I created a lightbox in jQuery that brings up a text input field, but for some reason I cannot type in the input field, it automatically deselects. If I hold down the mouse button and start typing then it works, but as soon as I let go it deleted all the text. Any idea why this might be happening?

Here's my code (sorry, I know its a lot, but the lightbox isn't showing up in jsfiddle)

HTML

```
<div id="submitanswerbutton">
<a href="#answer-box" class="login-window"><div class="btn btn-primary">Ask a Question</a></div>
<div id="answer-box" class="answer-popup">

</div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
 #submittextbutton{
float:right;
margin-top:5px;
margin-right:12px;
}

 #mask {
display: none;
background: #000; 
position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; 
z-index: 10;
width: 100%; height: 100%;
opacity: 0.5;
z-index: 999;
 }

 .answer-popup{
display:none;
font-size:14px;
background: #333;
padding: 10px;     
width:250px;
height:300px;
border: 1px solid black;
float: left;
font-size: 1.2em;
position: fixed;
top: 50%; left: 50%;
z-index: 99999;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #333333; /* CSS3 */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #333333; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #333333; /* Safari, Chrome */
border-radius:13px 13px 13px 13px;
    -moz-border-radius: 13px; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius: 13px; /* Safari, Chrome */
 }

 .answer-popup a {
color:white;
font-size:14px;
text-decoration:none;
background:#333;
}
```

​

JS

```
// Clicking on Ask a Question button on Answers page
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '#submitanswerbutton', function(event){

                //Getting the variable's value from a link 
        var answerBox = $(this).attr('href');

        //Fade in the Popup
        $('.answer-popup').fadeIn(300);

        //Set the center alignment padding + border see css style
        var popMargTop = ($(answerBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
        var popMargLeft = ($(answerBox).width() + 24) / 2; 

        $(answerBox).css({ 
            'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
            'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
        });

        // Add the mask to body
        $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
        $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

        return false;
    });

    // When clicking on the mask layer the popup closed    
    $('#mask').live('click', function() { 
      $('#mask , .answer-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
        $('#mask').remove();  

    }); 
    return false;
    });
});

// load Answers when click questions via Ajax
// load Answer when clicking question
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url;
    $('.question a').click(function(ev) {
        url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.answers').load('http://127.0.0.1:8000'+url, function(response){
        });
    return false;
    });

    $('body').on('click', '#submitanswerbutton', function(ev) {
        var pathname = window.location.pathname;
        $('.answer-popup').load(url+'add_answer/');
    });
    return false;
});    ​
```

Comment: You wouldn't be able to link to your website, would you?

Comment: No unfortunately its on a localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the #answer-box div outside of the #submitanswerbutton div:

```
<div id="submitanswerbutton">
    <a href="#answer-box" class="login-window"><div class="btn btn-primary">Ask a Question</a></div>
</div>
<div id="answer-box" class="answer-popup"></div>​
```

If the answerbox div is inside the first div, then every time that you click on the answerbox (for example to put the cursor into the text box), you end up calling the body click event which opens up another answerbox!

See this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/2vmCy/